# VS 2010 Ultimate Edition - hot to use msbuild to refresh exports of partial projects?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, build-automation, tfsbuild, database-schema

I use Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate Edition.

Situation is like this:
I have two databases solutions A and B. Solution A is exported as partial project. Solution B imports partial project from solution A.

I would like to build automatically solution B with the newest version of partial project from solution A. I need to do it automatically using build server. Partial project from solution A should be refreshed before each database build. Do I have to refresh also a partial project import from solution B after refreshing export in solution A?

Is it possible to make it through some command line? What command should I call and which parameters should I use?

Please help.

Answer (score -1):

Is it built automatically in the IDE? If yes, you can use `devenv /build <solution file>` for that.

Comment: This is not an answer. Sorry. :( You don't know what are you talking about. I found partial solution. There can be run command for VS but there are still two issues. One: popup window appears with question  and avialable answers yes/no. How to push automatically [yes] button? The second one is that I don't know how to run command from outside of visual studio.

Comment: @truthseeker: "You don't know what are you talking about." That is not a way to respond to someone that is trying to help you.

Comment: It's better to say nothing than something what is not related to the topic.